# how to use docx4js in a project?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, ms-word, docx

Hello i've been tryng to use this library docx4js https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx4js  to convert a docx document to html,this is my code, when i try to upload a document i get undefined,....i can't find any examples on this,...can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="docx4js.js"></script>
    <script>
      var Docx = require("docx4js");
      let val = "";
      let element;
      function test(input) {
        val = input.files[0];
        Docx.docx.load(input.files[0]).then(function (docx) {
          element = docx.render();
          document.querySelector("#docx").innerHTML = element;
          console.log(element);
          console.dir(element);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="file"
      style="position: absolute; top: 0"
      onchange="test(this)"
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <div id="docx"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```